# Keeping the bgcolor of a <td> within defined height/width constraints

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been tasked with creating a clean template for our HTML newsletter with circulates to about 70k subscribers. As expected, they're hoping for it to be as consistent across as many e-mail clients as possible, so I'm following widely suggested HTML e-mail practice and using nested tables and in-line style.

I'm trying to set a `bgcolor` to each `<td>` that displays an image - the reason being that if someone has the images on their e-mail client turned off, they'll still be able to see the shape of the table cells (and their experience will still be somewhat visual), but I'm having difficulty keeping the bgcolor within the cell, it seems to bleed into the space between cells. Here's an example:

```
  <tr>
     <td width="200" height="200" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
       <img src="image.png" height="200" width="200" alt="Image!">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

From this code, instead of the background being invisible under the image when the image is visible because they're both 200x200, I see about 10px of the grey pushing down into the bottom and right side of the image and intruding into the white space around the cells. What is going on and how can I fix this?

EDIT: Here's an image of what it's doing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the css style of the table to border-collapse? Like so:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

If that has no effect, and there is no margin on the images, have you tried setting padding to 0?

Comment: Cellpadding is set to zero in the table tag. 

If you get e-mailed responses, I apologize... I couldn't get the code to format properly so I deleted a few responses to you.

Comment: No worries! :) The border-collapse property is different to cellpadding or cellspacing, so it may pay to give it a go. 


Sorry I didn't explain the "padding" part of my answer better too - I was thinking of specifically setting padding on the image to zero, just to make sure there wasn't something going on. However, you updated with the picture illustrating the problem, so I don't think that applies.

Comment: I'll read up on the border-collapse property and keep messing with it, I'll also mess with the cellpadding on the image. Thanks for your attention and I'll let you know!

Comment: Still can't figure out how to make it work by editing the current tags, I used a work around using a `<div>`, which may pose some problems for certain e-mail clients, but we'll see....

Thanks again for everyone's help!

Comment: You're welcome! If you wanted to, feel free to post the code you're using here, and I'll try and take a look at it for you - otherwise, good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` properties on the table tag?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp

Comment: Set the cellspacing to a value great than 0. That is the space between cells which is why there is no gap between cells and their background color.

Comment: Setting the cellspacing to greater than zero increased the white space between the cells, but I can still see the grey bgcolor peeking out the bottom of the image. What else could I be missing? :(

Comment: do your images have any margin? I don't see that you are setting a margin but perhaps img tags have margin in the various email client user agents?

Comment: Nope, no margins. Adding a `style="margin-bottom:*px"` to the image pushed the image up and expanded the space in which the grey bgcolor was peeking...